# Is there a way to "mute" an alert tone that's already in the process of playing?

Tags: notifications, audio, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S5 and have it set to play a fairly loud 15 second alert if I get a text message in the middle of the night (I'm frequently on-call).  I usually wake up within the first 5 seconds and would like an easy way to stop the alert from finishing the rest of the playback.  Is this possible?

On other phones (for example Blackberry), pressing virtually any button would silence an alert in progress.  That doesn't seem to work for the Galaxy S5.

Comment: 1.  What happens if you move your phone to silent mode while the sound is still playing?  2.  Could you get your boss to phone you (instead of sending an SMS) when s/he needs your services in the middle of the night?